# For all $X \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ there exist $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $|X| < n$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

True or false?

For all $X \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ there exist $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $|X| < n$.

I think this is false because if you pick $X = \mathbb{N}$, then the inequality $|X| < n$ does not hold. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. But you should give your reasoning if this is an exercise. Try arguing that X have a subset of every order and so assuming it have a finite cardinality contradict this fact (how many subsets can a set of cardinality n have?)

Comment: What do you mean by "$X$ have a subset of every order?"

Comment: and that cardinality would be $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ right?

Comment: Yes. And for your choice there are infinite number of subsets, given any k there is the subset of all element smaller than k. So there is at least one subset per Natural number and thus infinite number of subsets

Comment: Yes. And for your choice there are infinite number of subsets, given any k there is the subset of all element smaller than k. So there is at least one subset per Natural number and thus infinite number of subsets

Comment: Can you please clarify on "given any k there is the subset of all element smaller than k"? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your answer $X=\mathbb{N} $is correct. In fact, any infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ will do.

Comment: Such as $\{n \in \mathbb{N}:2n\}$?